# How to get latest updated record in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to get latest updated record in oracle ?

```
before

table - test:
a    b    timestamp
1    5    2018/12/13 10:13:18
3    7    2018/12/13 10:13:18
4    8    2018/12/13 10:13:18

update query done

after:

a    b    timestamp
1    5    2018/12/13 10:13:18
3    7    2018/12/13 10:13:18
4    5    2018/12/13 10:13:18
```

Record has been changed using update query moreover timestamps of all data has same date. How to select latest updated record
?
using Rowid and timestamps are not working.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If there are archive logs for the search period. You must use the utility LogMiner.
Example 1.

```
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39306_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.NEW); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39307_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39308_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.add_logfile(LOGFILENAME => '/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2/admin/edcu/arc_redo_log/1_39309_769799469.dbf', OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.addfile); 
EXECUTE DBMS_LOGMNR.START_LOGMNR(OPTIONS => DBMS_LOGMNR.DICT_FROM_ONLINE_CATALOG);

SELECT 
to_char(timestamp,'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'),
operation,username,  
os_username,
machine_name,
session_info,
sql_redo

 FROM v$logmnr_contents
where 
seg_owner='MANAGER' and  seg_name='TEST2'

14-12-2017 09:40:20 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  create table test2 (p1 number);
14-12-2017 09:40:47 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c117'));
14-12-2017 09:40:53 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c119'));
14-12-2017 09:40:57 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c137'));
14-12-2017 09:41:01 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1") values (HEXTORAW('c20219'));
14-12-2017 09:41:45 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  alter table test2 add (p2 varchar2(200));
14-12-2017 09:42:12 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c20219'),HEXTORAW('746573743220746573743120'));
14-12-2017 09:42:24 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:46:24 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:46:25 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:46:26 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:46:27 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:46:28 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("COL 1","COL 2") values (HEXTORAW('c2021a'),HEXTORAW('746573743420746573743420'));
14-12-2017 09:54:37 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   comment on table test2 is  'test';
14-12-2017 10:16:36 DDL     MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  alter table test2 add  (p3 varchar2(100));
14-12-2017 10:17:07 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("P1","P2","P3") values ('125','test6','test4 ');
14-12-2017 10:17:08 INSERT  MANAGER DeminDV KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN   login_username=MANAGER client_info= OS_username=DeminDV Machine_name=KRW\IVC-PTK-DEMIN  insert into "MANAGER"."TEST2"("P1","P2","P3") values ('125','test6','test4 ');
'
```

Example 2. Using Flashback Features

```
   update manager.test2 set p2='test10' where p1=125;
    commit;

    SELECT versions_xid XID, versions_startscn START_SCN,
      versions_endscn END_SCN, versions_operation OPERATION,
      p1, p2, p3 FROM manager.test2
    VERSIONS BETWEEN SCN MINVALUE AND MAXVALUE;

XID                                         START_SCN           END_SCN       OPERATION       P1     P2     P3                                                                                                   
---------------------- ------------------------ ---------------------- --------------- ---------- -------- ------
08000E000DD70900        1374388524564                                                 U          125 test10   test4                                                                                                
08000E000DD70900        1374388524564                                                 U          125 test10   test4                                                                                                
08000E000DD70900        1374388524564                                                 U          125 test10                                                                                                            
08000E000DD70900        1374388524564                                                 U          125 test10                                                                                                                       
                                                               1374388524564                     125 test4 test4    
                                                               1374388524564                     125 test4 test4    
                                                               1374388524564                     125 test6 test4 
                                                               1374388524564                     125 test6 test4      



            SELECT  xid, start_scn , commit_scn COMMIT,operation OP, logon_user ,undo_sql FROM flashback_transaction_query
                   WHERE xid = HEXTORAW('08000E000DD70900');

    XID                      START_SCN  COMMIT                OP    LOGON_USER                           UNDO_SQL                                                                                             
-------------------------------- -------------------------------- -------------------------------------- --------------------------------- ------------------------------------                                                        
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test6' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAM';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test6' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAL';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAK';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAJ';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAI';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAH';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAG';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   UPDATE  MANAGER update "MANAGER"."TEST2" set "P2" = 'test4 test4 ' where ROWID = 'AAA2wgAAbAAAAEsAAF';
        08000E000DD70900    1374388524537   1374388524564   BEGIN   MANAGER
```

Comment: I have give example as well. If any other way, plz suggest.